# How packets traverse tun+ adapter on firewall

Tags: networking, vpn, firewall, iptables, openvpn

I am familiar with Iptables, and recently I wanted to build a statefull firewall which is connected to a openvpn server.

If someone is willing to explain, how for example `eth0` (WAN), `eth1` (LAN) and `tun0` (VPN) pass the packets between each other?

I am talking about `FORWARD` chain. I have no troubles for setting a firewall with two NIC's, but I am getting confused if I try to set it up with OpenVPN.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two independent packet flows – one for the original packets from LAN, and another for encapsulated packets towards WAN.

For example, a LAN client tries to reach a remote host via the VPN:

1. The original packet goes through FORWARD and is forwarded from `eth1` to `tun0`, where it's consumed by OpenVPN.
2. OpenVPN sends a new "VPN" packet, which goes through OUTPUT and is sent from the firewall to `eth0`.

Same for replies from VPN to LAN:

1. The VPN packets are received on `eth0`, go through INPUT, and are received by OpenVPN on the firewall.
2. The decapsulated "original" packets appear as if they were received through `tun0`, and go through FORWARD to `eth1` again.

So as far as iptables is concerned, `tun0` is just a regular network interface that's connected to yet another network – it is no different from e.g. having an eth2 physically connected with a very long cable.